# Shortcut for Refresh All Projects?

Tags: textmate

I began to use Textmate. When it's focused, it read the project directory recursively and it stops responding for a while.

So I installed ReMate plugin and it adds option for 'Disable Refresh on Regaining Focus'. It's good. But when I add a file, I have to right click on the Project Drawer and select 'Refresh All Projects' to open the new file.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for 'Refresh All Projects'? Or is there a better way for my usage?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

If the choice is available in a regular menu you can:

1. Open up System Preferences (under the Apple menu)
2. Select Keyboard
3. Select Shortcuts tab
4. Click the + to add a shortcut which then presents you with a dropdown of all the apps on your Mac
5. Select Textmate then select the menu item and assign a keyboard shortcut

Comment: I didn't know about this great feature of OS X. Unfortunately it didn't work in this specific case as the menu is only in the Context Menu. Thanks anyway.